# curl in Xamp required

Tags: php, html

hai

i installed the magento in my Xampp  but i got an error message blow

PHP Extension "curl" must be loaded

How to load curl in XAMPP

Answer (score 2):

edit the php.ini and remove the semi-colon from the line that looks something like:
; extension=php_curl.dll

Then restart the server process.

If you don't know where your php.ini is, use a phpinfo page to make it tell you which one is currently being used:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Focus on the entry "Loaded Configuration File"